# Failed to Attach these Types of code VS 2015.U2 Intellitrace

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio, intellitrace

When I run any Project (C# Console, Asp.net, etc) and Compile it (Press F5) and after closing it this message appears: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c10yk.png]

and it appears when I first open the project.

I have tried to install VS 2015 Update 2, but nothing... (after uninstalling VS 2015 Update 1), then any project after compile shows this message after closing it.

This message does not appears when I start the project without debugging.

Comment: I faced this problem when I changed the .net version from 4.5 to 3.5.When I returned to 4.5 , the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install VS 2015 Update 1, uninstall Update 1 and then install Update 2. But I couldn't reproduce the bug on a clean virtual machine. I suspect this is a setup issue. Do you see any problem in uninstall Update 1 or install Update 2? Do you see the same error when you uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" (in your project properties -> Debug tab) and press F5 to start debugging?